# Issues with the "subprocess" module in Python 3.9.1 (or 3.9.2) - "subprocess.Popen" doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

When my script has the `.pyw` extension, the function `subprocess.Popen` doesn't work, but if I use the `.py` extension, it works. Actually the extension is not so important, the main point is if I use the terminal or not to run the script, if I don't use it I have the issue, otherwise no issues.

This wird behaviout happens only in my PC with Python 3.9.1 or 3.9.2 (the last version currently available). However I have another PC with Python 3.9.0, and there the issue doesn't exist.

I'll give you an example. here I have two scripts, below is the first one named `main_script.pyw`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sys, subprocess

def MyFunction():
    subprocess.Popen(["start", sys.executable, "script.py"], shell=True)

parent=Tk()
parent.geometry("300x250+370+100")
parent.title("Test")

TestButton=ttk.Button(parent, text="start", width=16, command=MyFunction)
TestButton.place(x=10, y=10)

parent.mainloop()
```

Here is the second one named `script.py`:

```
a=input("give me a number: ")
```

Both of them are placed in the same directory. The user can start the second script using the function `subprocess.Popen` only if the extension of the main script is `.py`, otherwise he can't. How can I solve the issue? Is it a BUG?

I attached a GIF too:

[image]

**UPDATE! 1**
I tried to install Python 3.9.0 in a virtual machine, and there I found the same issue described before! so, I can't understand why in my PC, with the same version, the script works. if I type `python --version` in my terminal the output is `Python 3.9.0`. Here is another GIF to show you that it works:

[image]

In the installation path (`C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`), I saw two folders, `Python39` and `Python38-32`. Probably the second one is a refuse from an old installation, I don't know, but maybe it helps to make the script work. What do you think?

I just want to run CLI scripts via Tkinter as you saw in the last GIF (without using the terminal of course). How can I reach my goal?

**UPDATE! 2**
I'm not sure but, maybe it's a Windows issue. I tried to run Google Chrome using the `subprocess.Popen(["start", sys.executable, "script.py"], shell=True)` instruction (before you have to open the terminal in the Chrome installation folder `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application`) and it worked only in my PC where I never have issues, but with the other one Chrome didn't start, and in the terminal I got this output (I use ConEmu as terminal):

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(["start", sys.executable, "chrome.exe"], shell=True) 
<Popen: returncode: None args: ['start', 'C:\\Users\\aquer\\AppData\\Local\\...>

SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x83' in file C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Current directory:
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application

Command to be executed:
"C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"   chrome.exe

ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

I tried to open the terminal in Admin mode but, also in this case, Google Chrome didn't start. Where is the issue from your point of viewes?

Comment: Pyw doesn’t open a command prompt, that’s why you use pyw.

Comment: yeah, if the `main_script` uses the `.pyw` extension, the `subprocess.Popen` function can't run the `script.py` file (a CLI software). If I run the `main_script.pyw` via terminal, the `subprocess.Popen` function works but, I just want to use the GUI, I don't want to use the CLI to run the main script. this issue doesn't exist in Python 3.9.0.

Comment: In python 3.9.0 when the new process is starting does a terminal window pop up?

Comment: yes, In python 3.9.0 the `script.py` is opened in a new terminal, even if the `main_script.pyw` has been opened via GUI (with a double click I mean and no terminal).

Comment: So the problem is in how Python 3.9.1 `pythonw.exe` handles input requests. In Python 3.9.1 they are ignored unlike Python 3.9.0 they are handled by spawning a new terminal shell

Comment: ciao TheLizzard. just to be sure, I tried to install Python 3.9.0 in a virtual machine, and there I have the same issue described before! so, I can't understand why in my PC, with the same version, the script works. if I type `python --version` in my terminal the output is  `Python 3.9.0`.

Comment: So you are saying that it only occurs in some installations of Python 3.9.0? If that is true, either something is wrong with your python installation or its a bug in python

Comment: I just update my topic adding a new GIF. So you can see that `Pythonw` can open the terminal (see the path in the CMD title bar).

Comment: Running Python as a subprocess of itself is often just an unnecessary complication. Is there a particular reason you don't simply `import` the code you want to run, and call it natively?

Comment: Change `sys.executable` to `"python"` or `"pythonw"` depending on the file extension of the program you are trying to run

Comment: @tripleee my real software has to open different kind of scripts, not only python ones. from my side it doesn't matter what kind of script or application the user want to open, the `subprocess.Popen` function has to work! unfortunately, from the Python point of view, it works only with GUI applications as I showed you in my first GIF.

Comment: @TheLizzard If I change the `sys.executable` instruction to `C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe`, the script works like in my second GIF that I showed you before (with pythonw.exe it didn't work) but it's not the solution for me, because my real software needs to open different kind of CLI/GUI scripts and applications. It's not just for Python, I chose the `sys.executable` instruction because I don't know the nature of the script that the user are going to run.

Comment: But `sys.executable` specifically runs Python.

Comment: @TurboC I think that you are confused on what `sys.executable` is. It stores the filename of the program used to start the python script. If the main python file has `.pyw` extension, `sys.executable` will be `pythonw.exe` If the main python file has `.py` extension, `sys.executable` will be `python.exe`.

Comment: @tripleee Read my comment above.

Comment: @TheLizzard What about if you use my two scripts? do you have my same issue? I think it's a Windows issue but I'm not sure. I just updated my Topic. Can you tell me what do you think about it?

Comment: The issue can't be in Windows if it works for Python 3.9.0. I am using Python 3.7 and it doesn't work.

Comment: @TheLizzard But as I wrote before, I also tried to install Python 3.9.0 in a virtual machine, and I saw the same issue! so I don't know why the issue doesn't occurs in my PC and in the other ones yes.

Comment: @TurboC is there anything different between the python/windows on your virtual machine vs the real computer? There is no way that you have the same set up and get different results so something must be different.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is because for `.py` files Windows uses `python.exe` and for `.pyw` files Windows uses `pythonw.exe`. The problem is that `sys.executable` has the file location of the program used to start the main python file (`python.exe` when the extension is `.py` and `pythonw.exe` when the extension is `.pyw`). So the problem is that you are trying to start the `.py` program using the python executable that is for `.pyw` file extensions.

In cmd:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python.exe'
```

in IDLE (doesn't have the terminal window):

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\pythonw.exe'
```

Therefore, you have to decide which program (`python.exe` or `pythonw.exe`) you want to use. You can do it based on the file extension.

Comment: mm.. with Python 3.9.0 I don't have the issue. my real program use Tkinter GUI, and it needs to run some GUI or CLI scripts. in the new Python versions it can't run the CLI scripts anymore and I would very like to solve this weird behaviour.

Comment: @TurboC Look in your python installation folder for Python 3.9.0 and 3.9.2 and tell if there are 2 files named `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe`.

Comment: I have both of them in both of my PCs (the first one with Python 3.9.2 and the second one with Python 3.9.0).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to open a command prompt from your `main_script.py` manually, and execute `script.py` in there, if you really **have** to execute it as an extra process. If you do not have to, just add `import script` at the place you want the content of `script.py` to be executed, or, even better, wrap the code in `script.py` into a function, import `script.py` at the top of `main_script.py` and call the funcction at the approproate place. For the first solution, there is an example on [DataToFish](https://datatofish.com/command-prompt-python/) that has almost the same code as you (using tkinter GUI a.o., you have to scroll down a bit to find the example with a GUI). In short, you just have execute `cmd /c {sys.executable} script.pyw` from `main_script.py`.